# Передача данных между сценами

Tags: swift

Как мне передать переменную со значением из одной сцены в другую?
Для view у меня получилось сделать, а для scene не могу сообразить...

Comment: так и передайте: `scene2.var = scene1.var;` либо показывайте код, если там все сложнее

Comment: там нет файла Next.swift

Comment: ой, перепутала, в EndScene.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В EndScene объявить внутреннюю переменную score

```
class EndScene: SKScene{
    var RestartB : UIButton!
    internal var score : NSInteger = 0
```

при создании EndScene передавать score из GameScene

```
func collisionWithPerson(En: SKSpriteNode, Person: SKSpriteNode){
    En.removeFromParent()
    Person.removeFromParent()

    let endScene = EndScene() //не путать endScene и EndScene
    endScene.score = self.score
    view?.presentScene(endScene)
    Scorelbl.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

На будущее предложил бы почитать синглтон, я думаю вам много данных надо будет гонять по всей программе. [Тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/198470/) хорошая статья.

Comment: добавил в ответ про синглтон

Comment: Попробовала, не получается сделать, чтобы значение score в EndScene и  GameScene были одинаковы, может ScoreLbl тоже передать?

Comment: Я получается хочу ввести условие в EndScene:
if (score == 2){
self.view.addSubview(RestartB)
}
Но видимо переменная не передается т.к. кнопка вообще не появляется

Comment: почему именно 2? почему не if (score >= 2) ??

Comment: Ну это в принципе не особо важно, в любом случае почему-то не появляется кнопка

Comment: у меня работает - набил 6 очков, показало 6 очков. попробуйте в didMoveToView добавить `print(self.score)`

Comment: Выдает 0, хоть очков было 7

Comment: хм. а точно весь код из ответа скопировали?

Comment: Да, скопировала весь

Comment: О, убираю новый Label нормально работает, тоесть я на экране не смогу это число выводить?

Comment: что такое новый label?

Comment: Ну я создала ScoreL = UILabel() и ему прописала ScoreL.text = "\(score)" почему-то не показывает

Comment: А может в этом проблема... Я могу так написать? в EndScene didMove
if (score >=2){
self.view.addSubview(RestartB)
}

Comment: давайте еще раз. в EndScene если в didMoveToView добавить print(self.score) тчо показывает?

Comment: если убрать и Label и условие, то все правильно показывает, если я пытаюсь все это вернуть, то пишет 0

Comment: тогда я предлагаю считать этот вопрос отвеченным, и задать новый про label

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо